# Web application with Node.js and WPF client-side - is it viable?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, node.js, web-applications

I'll take part in a beginner Node.js course in a month and since I want to make myself at least a bit familiar with Node in advance, I'm wondering what client-side technology to use with Node(mainly for studying and fun). While javascript would be an obvious answer, I'm kind of more interested in using WPF to create a client application. Since I'm far from an expert in both fields, I have the following questions:

1. Is it meaningful to use WPF and Node.js together?
2. What are the pros and cons to a WPF/Node combination?